# A simple web service in PHP, Get method

Tags: php, mysql, json, wikitude

I am trying to develop a simple web service which serves my Wikitude Augmented reality app with data. The data will be served as JSON from and it will  be retrieved from MYSQL database. So far, I was able to connect to my database and get the data as JSON format.

However, I need to further develop it to make HTTP Get Method requests. Here is my PHP script

```
<?PHP
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tutorial") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $getData = "select * from places";
    $qur = $connection->query($getData);

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qur)){

    $msg[] = array("id" => $r['id'], "longitude" => $r['longitude'], "latitude" => $r['latitude'], "description" => $r['description'], "name" => $r['name']);
    }
    $json = $msg;

    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);

    @mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Currently, if I make requests for instance as
`http://localhost/json_internet2.php?longitude=13.88345` the result is all the data from the database. Hence, it is not working.

how can I proceed further with this? Any help would be benificial.

Thanks

Comment: Well it's doing what you've told it to, that is, to return everything. What exactly are you wanting to happen and what have your tried to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database has a "longitude" column, you need to modify the SQL query to take into account the GET variable (longitude in your example) and use it to filter out the result.

Example:

```
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tutorial") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$getData = "select * from places";

if(isset($_GET['longitude']) && !empty($_GET['longitude'])){
   $longitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['longitude']);
    $getData = "select * from places WHERE longitude = '$longitude' ";    
 }

$qur = $connection->query($getData);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qur)){

$msg[] = array("id" => $r['id'], "longitude" => $r['longitude'], "latitude" => $r['latitude'], "description" => $r['description'], "name" => $r['name']);
}
$json = $msg;

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

@mysqli_close($conn);
```

This is beyond the scope of this question, but note that for security issues, you should really use PDO and prepared statements. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks very much "pixeline". However, it did not work for me. There is an errror. I also have to consider latitude. So my query would be for instance as http://localhost/json_internet2.php?longitude=13.88345&latitude=46.611204

Comment: What error? Please be accurate. Do you actually have a "longitude" column in your database table? make sure you use the name. The provided code is assuming you have a "longitude" column with the longitude data for each row. Same for latitude.